# OpenCV: Pedestrian training data for lbp cascades

Tags: opencv, haar-wavelet

Where i can find training data or maybe complete lbp cascade for pedestrian detection?

If there is a haarcascades, it should be and the training data which can be used to traine  lbp cascades, i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most widely used dataset for pedestrain detection
[caltech](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/CaltechPedestrians/)

Also look [Here](http://www.gavrila.net/Research/Looking_at_People/looking_at_people.html)